# Are multiple player profiles supported?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

I'd like to be able to track my own progress in the game separately from my children. I've not yet purchased the game, but would like to know if it supports multiple player profiles for the sake of progress tracking (similar to how the PopCap games Plants Vs Zombies and Bejewelled 3 do).

Comment: I've edited your question slightly to remove the PC requirement; I suspect the profiles should function the same, regardless of platform.  If it turns out that PC behaves differently in this regard, feel free to add the PC tag to your question.

Comment: No problem. I initially stipulated that since it's also out on the Wii U. Console games often have the multiple player profiles feature, whereas PC games often rely on actually logging into a different PC user account. I'm hoping the PC version has the console style player profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a copy of the `savedata` subfolder in the Scribblenauts install directory allows you to copy your current game data. You can then delete the original with the in-game tool, and use your new save.

When you want to change save states, quit Scribblenauts and swap the standard `savedata` folder with your backup `savedata` folder.

The Scribblenauts install folder is either `C:\Program Files\WB Games\Scribblenauts Unlimited` or `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Scribblenauts`. For 64-bit, it will be in `Program Files (x86)` instead.

Comment: When i do the things you say, and reopen Scribblenauts, I have a new game.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple saves by copying the `C:\Program Files\WB Games\Scribblenauts Unlimited` folder to a new location. (If you're on a 64-bit computer, the folder will probably be in `C:\Program Files (x86)` instead.)

The saves are located locally in this folder along with other game data. This will mean that you will eat up another 1.7 GB of space on your drive. Your best bet would also be to set up multiple shortcuts on your desktop and add the name for the user to this shortcut. It's not the best way to have multiple saves, but we have to work with what the creators give us.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no subfolders with the game save data -- or even that the data is in the Program Files folder? Because if it is, then it would require administrator privileges to save the game, and I doubt that -- it'd more likely be in `%APPDATA%`.

Comment: You can make a copy of the `savedata` subfolder in the `Scribblenauts` folder. Then you can delete the data in-game to create a blank save for the new person. When you want to switch profiles, you can swap these folders instead of using two completely different install folders.

Comment: @Keeblebrox I'll test this shortly.

Comment: @Keeblebrox , this works fine. If you make this an official answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Rob Sounds good. I made it into an official answer. Thanks!